Evaluating $\int_{r_i}^{r_f}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{2GM \left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r_i}\right)}}$
How do we solve this integral step by step?
$$t=\int_{ r_i}^{r_f}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{2GM \left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{r_i}\right)}}$$
$$t=\int_{r_0}^{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{2GM\left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{r_0}\right)
}}$$

what is GM, I though it was geometric mean, or even arithmetic geometric means, but this requires two variables, so. also inners of parenthesis is negative, like the feedback you are likely to receive for a dry post (no show of personal effort).

@zwim Im sure GM is Gravitational constant and M is mass, probably gravitational potential calculation

@Bml avoid \display and \left\right in titles to minimize the vertical impact on question page.

@zwim Thank you for the advice. Really appreciated :-)

This question is similar to: Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}}$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. For this integral to be real requires $r_f<r_i$, making the integral negative. Is that intentional? Maybe you want to exchange the integration limits.

$$t=\int_{ r_i}^{r_f}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{2GM \left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{r_i}\right)}}$$
This is essentially calculating an integral of the below form
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{r_i}{2GM}}\int_{ r_i}^{r_f}\frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{ r_i-r}}\mathrm{d}r$$
Consider, $$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a-x}}\,dx=-\sqrt{ax-x^2}-a\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-x}{x}}\right)+c$$
The above integral can be solved by substituting $t=\sqrt{\frac{a-x}{x}}$ and then referring to standard integrals,
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{r_i}{2GM}}\int_{r_i}^{r_f} \frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{r_i-r}}\,dr=-\sqrt{r_ir-r^2}-r_i\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_i-r}{r}}\right)|_{r_i}^{r_f}=-\sqrt{\frac{r_i}{2GM}}\left(\sqrt{r_ir_f-r_f^2}+r_i\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_i-r_f}{r_f}}\right)\right)$$
$$\boxed{t=-\sqrt{\frac{r_i}{2GM}}\left(\sqrt{r_ir_f-r_f^2}+r_i\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_i-r_f}{r_f}}\right)\right)}$$
I'm guessing you got this integral after applying energy conservation

However, if $r_i$ was $r_f$ in your original integral,
$$t=\int_{ r_i}^{r_f}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{2GM \left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{r_f}\right)}}$$
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{2GM}}\int_{ r_i}^{r_f}\frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{ r_f-r}}\mathrm{d}r$$
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{2GM}}\,\int_{r_i}^{r_f} \frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{r_f-r}}\,dr=-\sqrt{r_fr-r^2}-r_f\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_f-r}{r}}\right)|_{r_i}^{r_f}=\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{2GM}}\left(\sqrt{r_ir_f-r_i^2}+r_f\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_f-r_i}{ri}}\right)\right)$$
for a special case of $r_i\to 0$ and $r_f \to nR$
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{n^3R^3\pi^2}{8GM}}$$



The final expression $I$, obtained does not include the $\sqrt{\frac{r_i}{2GM}}$ term multiplied(intentional) as the image focuses on how the integral was solved.

If we used the substitution suggested below, our integral
$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a-x}}\,dx \underset{x=a\sin^2(t)\implies t = \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\right)}\to 2a\int \sin^2(t)\,dt$$
$$I=2a\int \sin^2(t)\,dt=at-\frac{a}{2}\sin(2t)+C$$
$$I=a\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\right)-\frac{a}{2}\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\right)\right)+C$$
Getting it back to our original form,
$$a \to r_i, x \to r$$
$$I=r_i\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{r_i}}\right)-\frac{r_i}{2}\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{r_i}}\right)\right)+C$$
Apply the bounds,
$$I=r_i\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{r_i}}\right)-\frac{r_i}{2}\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{r_i}}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi r_i}{2}$$
Keeping track of a factor $\sqrt{\frac{r_i}{2GM}}$ being multiplied,
$$\boxed{I=\sqrt{\frac{r_i}{2GM}}\left(r_i\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{r_i}}\right)-\frac{r_i}{2}\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{r_i}}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi r_i}{2}\right)}$$
However, if $r_i$ was $r_f$ in your original integral,
For a special case of $r_i\to 0$ and $r_f \to nR$
$$I=nR\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{nR}}\right)-\frac{nR}{2}\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{nR}}\right)\right)+C$$
Applying the bounds $[r_i=0, r_f=nR]$,
$$I=\frac{nR\pi}{2}$$
Keeping track of a factor $\sqrt{\frac{r_f}{2GM}}\left(\implies \sqrt{\frac{nR}{2GM}}\right)$ being multiplied, (notice in the factor, $r_i$ is swapped with $r_f$)
$$\boxed{t=\sqrt{\frac{nR}{2GM}}\left(\frac{nR\pi}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{n^3R^3\pi^2}{8GM}}}$$
Essentially getting the same result as before.

I don't get the part where you solved $$\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}dx$$

@AnjanSharma I have included an image(apologies for not typesetting it, not enough time), hope this helps

To evaluate $\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}\mathrm dx$, IMO $x=a\sin^2\theta$ would be a fast approach.

@MathGuy, definitely! multiple approaches out there.
